# What is the general form of this integral?

Tags: integration

Trying to tabulate a function involving the integral

$$I(m)=\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos(m\beta)}{\sqrt{1+\xi\cos\beta}}d\beta,$$

I've found that for $m=0,1,2,...$ it does have a closed form in terms of [complete elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind). Namely, *Mathematica* gives$^\dagger$ the following results:

$$I(0)=\frac2{\sqrt{1+\xi}}K\left(\frac{2\xi}{1+\xi}\right),$$
$$I(1)=\frac2{\xi\sqrt{1+\xi}}\left((1+\xi)E\left(\frac{2\xi}{1+\xi}\right)-K\left(\frac{2\xi}{1+\xi}\right)\right),$$
$$I(2)=-\frac2{3\xi^2\sqrt{1+\xi}}\left(4(1+\xi)E\left(\frac{2\xi}{1+\xi}\right)+(\xi^2-4)K\left(\frac{2\xi}{1+\xi}\right)\right),$$
$$I(3)=-\frac2{15\xi^3\sqrt{1+\xi}}\left((9\xi^3+9\xi^2-32\xi-32)E\left(\frac{2\xi}{1+\xi}\right)+(32-17\xi^2)K\left(\frac{2\xi}{1+\xi}\right)\right),$$
$$\ldots.$$

Here $E$ and $K$ follow the argument conventions for [`EllipticE`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticE.html) and [`EllipticK`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticK.html).

We can see some polynomials appear as coefficients of $E$ and $K$. Is there a general form to represent them, so that the $I(m)$ would be in closed form for the general case of $m\in\mathbb Z^+$?

<sub><sub>$^\dagger$I obtained these expressions by finding indefinite integral with `Integrate` and applying Newton-Leibnitz formula, otherwise *Mathematica* takes too long to evaluate most of them if I directly try definite integration</sub></sub>

Comment: i think an explicit recursion formula might be obtained by using the recursion formula of chebychev polynomials... i see if i can find something